# SQL Server how to tell if a set of values are different from another set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to determine if a set of values is different or the same from another set of values.

This seems simple but I'm stuck on the solution.

Here is the data...

```
declare @tv_mccvalues table(recnum int identity(1,1) primary key, mcc int, pursecandoid int, candoid int)

--CanDoId 801 the MCC values are the same
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 5001, 801)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 5001, 801)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 6001, 801)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 6001, 801)

--CanDoId 901 the MCC values are the different
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 7001, 901)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 7001, 901)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 8001, 901)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(5234, 8001, 901)

--CanDoId 1001 the MCC values are the same
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 9001, 1001)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 9001, 1001)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 10001, 1001)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 10001, 1001)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 11001, 1001)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 11001, 1001)

--CanDoId 1101 the MCC values are different
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 12001, 1101)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 12001, 1101)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 13001, 1101)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(2234, 13001, 1101)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 14001, 1101)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(6234, 14001, 1101)

--CanDoId 1201 the MCC values are the same
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 15001, 1201)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 16001, 1201)

--CanDoId 1201 the MCC values are different
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(1234, 17001, 1301)
insert into @tv_mccvalues(mcc, pursecandoid, candoid) values(7234, 18001, 1301)
```

The main key is the candoid.

I'm trying complete a query like this...

```
declare @candoid int = 801

if exists(
             select pursecandoid, mcc, count(mcc) as count
             from @tv_mccvalues t
             where candoid = @candoid
             group by pursecandoid, mcc
             having count(mcc) > 1
        )
begin
   select 'they are different'
end
else
begin
   select 'the are the same'
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats the expected result from the example data? We need to have some kind of ascii (text) based table with result so we can verify our query..

Comment: Do these records have some kind of group_id to determine the group

Comment: The group is the candoid. I have added some extra details that explains what my end result should be. I'm just look to see if they are different or the same.

Comment: Ok, for `@candoid int = 801` what is expected result? Just to show if there are the same records or not?

Answer (score -1):

Ok here are the results...

```
FIS 1    
Internet 0
```

My coworker from Chennai came up with the answer (Thank you Abdur).

Here it is...

```
declare @candoid int = 1001

SELECT mcc
FROM @tv_mccvalues a
where candoid= @candoid
and  mcc != ALL
( 
   SELECT mcc 
   FROM @tv_mccvalues b 
   WHERE  PurseCandoid <> a.pursecandoid 
   and candoid = a.candoid
)
```